# how to disable swipe effect of IOS platform in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm new to Ionic . I'm creating an phonegap app using ionic blank template.
When i swipe from left to right on second page of my app a black screen appears. I don't know from where it comes.I cant go back to previous page.I need to kill the app to solve this issue. 
  Following are code before and after the swipe :

before :

```
<ion-nav-view nav-view-transition="ios" nav-view-direction="forward" class="view-container disable-user-behavior" nav-swipe="">
<ion-pane class="pane" nav-view="active" style="opacity: 1; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0px 0px 10px; -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0px, 0px);">
<form name="memberInfo" ng-submit="saveMemberInfo(data)" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
......
</ion-pane>
</ion-nav-view>
```

after :

```
<ion-nav-view nav-view-transition="ios" nav-view-direction="back" class="view-container disable-user-behavior" nav-swipe=""><ion-pane class="pane" nav-view="active" style="opacity: 1; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039) 0px 0px 10px; -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0px, 0px); -webkit-transition: 0ms; transition: 0ms;">
<form name="memberInfo" ng-submit="saveMemberInfo(data)" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
........
</ion-pane><div class="pane" nav-view="cached" style="opacity: 0.9; -webkit-transform: translate3d(-33%, 0px, 0px); -webkit-transition: 0ms; transition: 0ms;"></div></ion-nav-view>
```

This issue is only appears in ios.

anybody knows how this issue is coming ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

According to the [Ionic forum](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/v1-0-0-rc-0-how-to-disable-swipe-to-go-back/18752) just use the following line of code in the config of your AngularJS module:

```
$ionicConfigProvider.views.swipeBackEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 11):

In the latest version of ionic you can also disable the swipe to go back feature only for certain views by using can-swipe-back="false" on ion-view.

```
<ion-view can-swipe-back="false"></ion-view>
```

Comment: Always include the version in your answer even if it is the current latest. I do not know which version are you referring to.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote below code in app.js file .

```
angular.module(....)
.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider,$ionicConfigProvider){

    $ionicConfigProvider.views.swipeBackEnabled(false);

.
.
.
.//remaining code in config
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case code above is not working: in the `run` function you can add:

```
$ionicPlatform.views.swipeBackEnabled(false);
```

Comment: for information: add this code as last line in the run function. I was facing issues in rest of the code of run function if this line was added as first line.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there's a workaround using `$ionicSideMenuDelegate`.

```
$ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false);
```

Of course, you should inject the *delegate* into the controller's *dependencies*.