# How to disable Ionic gesture for go back to previous page

Tags: ionic-framework

It seems ionic has the gesture for go back to previous page auto turned on, how to disable this feature.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to disable swipe effect of IOS platform in ionic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30031086/how-to-disable-swipe-effect-of-ios-platform-in-ionic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30031994/3611632) just use the following line of code in `.config` of your AngularJS `module`:

```
$ionicConfigProvider.views.swipeBackEnabled(false);
```