# how to stop or prevent swipe left or right event in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

could you please tell me how to stop swipe left and right event .Actually I make a simple demo of **slide menu** Actually slide menu is display on my demo . It open when I swipe right .I don't want to do that ..I don't want to open slide menu when user use swipe left or right event .It only open when user use **top left icon( menu icon)** and also hide using same icon .In other words user toggle slide menu using top left icon.And don't want to display slide menu when user swipe left and right .

here is my code
 http://run.plnkr.co/taSxxNDMgBcJFP5A/#/app/playlists

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>


    <script src="controller.js"></script>
     <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

    <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30031086/how-to-disable-swipe-effect-of-ios-platform-in-ionic

Comment: @Ronnie i will check and update you

Comment: Not working please check ..Please give pluker if it is working on your side

Comment: you tested that in less than a minute? Can you give us the link to your plunkr in edit mode so we can test your code

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/1kQq5LVvENj1FDRuzlUY?p=preview ..That Question is different actually I need my slide menu not display when I swipe right.it only display when I click top left icon ..and also hide using same icon

Comment: please run that plunker ..!! and move swipe left and swipe right ..it display menu option or slide menu ..please check on full screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout,$ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
  $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(){
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false);
  });

  $scope.$on('$ionicView.leave', function(){
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(true);
  });
  ......
});
```

Include `$ionicSideMenuDelegate` and listen for the events: `$ionicView.enter` and `$ionicView.leave`